# AJAX POST - infrequent XHR Failed loading - data missing in PHP post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Likely a duplicate in theme/name, but no previous solutions will work either because I'm missing something or there is something else going on.

The form - seemingly at random - fails (not altering data in any field, just the defaults set in html) and when it does succeed the PHP file logs only two of the values, the second one and the fourth (both pure numbers/ints). The two it doesn't echo are 1: a text field and 3: a float.

This is the result the .php picks up -

```
Connected 
'' + '8080' + '' + '1'
```

Here is the .html and .js, what on earth am I missing here?

```
<form id="form_0" name="form_0" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" id="coinname" name="coinname" value="litecoin"><br>
        <input type="number" id="coins" name="coins" value="8080"><br>
        <input type="number" id="cost" name="cost" value="0.0808"><br>
        <input type="number" id="show" name="show" value="1"><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<script>
$("#form_0").submit(function() {

            var selectedcoin = $("#coinname").val();
            var coins = $("#coins").val();
            var buyprice = $("#cost").val();
            var show = $("#show").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "write-database.php",
                data: "selectedcoin=" + selectedcoin + "&coins=" + coins + "&buyprice=" + buyprice + "&show=" + show,
                success: function(data) {
                   alert(data);
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

and here is the .php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "#";
$password = "#";
$dbname = "#";

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else {
    echo "Connected <br>"; 
}

$selectedcoin=$_POST['selectedcoin'];
$coins=$_POST['coins'];
$buyprice=$_POST['buyprice'];
$show=$_POST['show'];
$sql= mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO coin_price (coin_name, coin, price, display) VALUES ('".$selectedcoin."','".$coins."','".$buyprice."','".$show."')");
echo "'$selectedcoin' + '$coins' + '$buyprice' + '$show'";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use serialize method to get all data from form values, as inputs names in $_POST global variable.

```
<form id="form_0" name="form_0" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" id="coinname" name="coinname" value="litecoin"><br>
        <input type="number" id="coins" name="coins" value="8080"><br>
        <input type="number" id="cost" name="cost" val="0.0808"><br>
        <input type="number" id="show" name="show" value="1"><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<script>
$("#form_0").submit(function() {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "write-database.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                   alert(data);
                }
            });
        });

</script>
<?php

$selectedcoin=$_POST['coinname'];
$coins=$_POST['coins'];
$buyprice=$_POST['cost'];
$show=$_POST['show'];
$sql= mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO coin_price (coin_name, coin, price, display) VALUES ('".$selectedcoin."','".$coins."','".$buyprice."','".$show."')");
echo "'$selectedcoin' + '$coins' + '$buyprice' + '$show'";

?>
```

Comment: thanks for the response, what you have written has cleaned things up and I'm now getting the data through to my php, but the XHR failure is still happening. The only way I can see if the data is going through is if I set action="write-database.php" in the form, when not doing that 90% of the time I get an empty alert(data) and XHR failed

Comment: turns out I was missing e.preventDefault(); in the js to disable the page refreshing... if you can add that to your answer above I will mark yours as correct

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't disabled the default submit behaviour that refreshes the page...

```
$("#form_0").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "write-database.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                   alert(data);
                }
            });
         });
```